# Not able to stop Hadoop IPC service

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce

I am using Hadoop IPC to create a sequencial number generating service, but not able to stop the server when the program exits. Could anybody help me?

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.InetAddress;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Map.Entry;

import org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration;
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem;
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.IntWritable;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.SequenceFile;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.Text;
import org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RPC;
import org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server;

import dk.aau.cs.cloudetl.common.CEConstants;
import dk.aau.cs.cloudetl.hadoop.fs.FSUtil;

public class SequenceServer extends Thread implements  ClientProtocol {

    Map<String, Integer> seqMap = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
    Configuration conf;
    Server server;
    Path seqFile;
    volatile private boolean running = true;        

    public SequenceServer(Configuration conf) {
        try {
            this.conf = conf;
            this.seqFile = new Path(CEConstants.META_DIR + Path.SEPARATOR
                    + "cloudETL.seq");

            InetAddress addr = InetAddress.getLocalHost();
            server = RPC.getServer(this, addr.getHostName(),CEConstants.SEQ_SERVER_PORT, 5, true, conf);

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        try {
            readSeqsFromHDFS();
            server.start();


            System.out.println("=============Start==============");
            while(running){
                sleep(5000);
            }
            System.out.println("=============END==============");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }



    private void readSeqsFromHDFS() {
        try {
            FileSystem fs = FileSystem.getLocal(conf);
            if (fs.exists(seqFile)) {
                SequenceFile.Reader reader = new SequenceFile.Reader(fs,
                        seqFile, conf);
                Text key = new Text();
                IntWritable value = new IntWritable();
                while (reader.next(key, value)) {
                    String name = key.toString();
                    int seq = value.get();
                    seqMap.put(name, seq);
                }
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private void writeSeqsToHDFS() {
        try {
            FileSystem fs = FileSystem.getLocal(conf);
            Path tmp = new Path(seqFile.getParent() + Path.SEPARATOR
                    + "tmp.seq");
            SequenceFile.Writer writer = SequenceFile.createWriter(fs, conf,
                    tmp, Text.class, IntWritable.class);
            for (Entry<String, Integer> entry : seqMap.entrySet()) {
                String name = entry.getKey();
                int seq = entry.getValue();
                writer.append(new Text(name), new IntWritable(seq));
            }
            writer.close();

            FSUtil.replaceFile(new File(tmp.toString()),
                    new File(seqFile.toString()));
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

    synchronized public void stopServer() {
        try {
            System.out.println(server.getNumOpenConnections() );
            server.stop();

            writeSeqsToHDFS();
            running = false;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public long getProtocolVersion(String protocol, long clientVersion)
            throws IOException {
        return versionID;
    }

    @Override
    synchronized public IntWritable nextSeq(Text name) {
        String seqName = name.toString();
        if (!seqMap.containsKey(seqName)) {
            seqMap.put(seqName, new Integer(CEConstants.SEQ_INCR_DELTA));
            return new IntWritable(0);
        } else {
            int ret = seqMap.get(seqName);
            seqMap.put(seqName, ret + CEConstants.SEQ_INCR_DELTA);
            return new IntWritable(ret);
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SequenceServer server = new SequenceServer(new Configuration());
        server.start();

        server.stopServer();
    }
}
```

I have another client program to to get the unique number. I wont post here.

---

Thanks for your answer. I know the problem as you said. However, my current problem is not able to stop the RPC server. As RPC server is running as daemon mode, even i run stop(), it still cannot exit. You can try this :

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.InetAddress;

import org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration;
import org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RPC;
import org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server;

public class Test {
    Server server;

    public Test() {
        try {
            InetAddress addr = InetAddress.getLocalHost();
            server = RPC.getServer(this, addr.getHostName(),16000, 5, true, new Configuration());
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public void start(){
        server.start();
    }

    public void stop(){
        server.stop();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Test test = new Test();
        test.start();
        test.stop();
    }
}
```

---

Thanks! But it still does not work. Could you try my example. You just copy and save as Test.java, then run it. You will see it is not able exit the main thread.

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.InetAddress;
import java.net.InetSocketAddress;

import org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.IntWritable;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.Text;
import org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RPC;
import org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server;

interface MyProtocal extends org.apache.hadoop.ipc.VersionedProtocol {
    public static final long versionID = 1L;

    IntWritable nextSeq(Text name);
}

public class Test implements MyProtocal {
    Server server;

    public Test() {
        try {
            InetAddress addr = InetAddress.getLocalHost();
            server = RPC.getServer(this, addr.getHostName(), 16000, 5, true,
                    new Configuration());
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public void start() {
        server.start();
    }

    public void stop() {
        server.stop();
    }

    @Override
    public long getProtocolVersion(String protocol, long clientVersion)
            throws IOException {
        return versionID;
    }

    @Override
    public IntWritable nextSeq(Text name) {
        return new IntWritable(999);
    }

    static class SEQ {
        MyProtocal client;

        public SEQ() {
            InetAddress addr;
            try {
                addr = InetAddress.getLocalHost();
                client = (MyProtocal) RPC.waitForProxy(MyProtocal.class,
                        MyProtocal.versionID,
                        new InetSocketAddress(addr.getHostName(), 16000),
                        new Configuration());
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        public void print() {
            System.out.println(client.nextSeq(new Text("aa")).get());
        }

        public void stop() {
            RPC.stopProxy(client);
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Test server = new Test();
        server.start();

        SEQ seq = new SEQ();
        seq.print();
        seq.stop();
        server.stop();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your design is broken. 
Why do you need to execute your program in a separate thread?

It is already running in the main thread and the RPC server is also running in a separate thread.

My suggestion would be to remove your own threading and just call the run method without the `while()` loop and stop the server after it.

**General note**: implement `Runnable` instead of extending from `Thread`

If you need to stick with your useless thread, then call in your main method `server.join()` and call stopServer() from the end of your `run` method.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I know the problem as you said. However, my current problem is not able to stop the RPC server. As RPC server is running as daemon mode, even i run stop(), it still cannot exit. You can try

Comment: Hi, I made minutes ago a benchmark between Hadoop RPC and avro. Here is my code: https://github.com/thomasjungblut/hama-avro/blob/master/src/de/jungblut/avro/AvroRPCTest.java#L141

Comment: In my case the server shuts  down perfectly.